# Gunicorn is stuck on docker run command with a Flask Application

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn, devops

I have my container `app_container` built, exposing port 8000 as per my application code.  The entry point to the container is `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "web_interface:app", "-w 4", "-t 90", "--log-level=info", "-b 127.0.0.1:8000",  "--reload"]`.

When I build and run the container with `docker run --link postgres_db_container --name foo app_container`, it runs the gunicorn command to the app. Unlike when i run the app locally, it stops at

```
[2017-06-19 16:01:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-06-19 16:01:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[2017-06-19 16:01:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-06-19 16:01:16 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2017-06-19 16:01:16 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2017-06-19 16:01:16 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2017-06-19 16:01:16 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
```

Anybody have a clue as to why the gunicorn process just stalls here, and does not continue?

No errors to go on either.  So if you have any idea how to get more info, Im all ears...

Edit:

When cancel the process with `control+c`, I see a test print message :

```
^C[2017-06-19 16:09:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2017-06-19 16:09:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
[2017-06-19 16:09:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
[2017-06-19 16:09:27 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
---- Generate Mapping ----
---- Preparing Databases ----
```

So it seems gunicorn is hung up on some process, but I dont know how to find out what it is.

Comment: And, is your app able to process requests?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that in there, but no.

Comment: oh.. Listen at `"-b 0.0.0.0:8000"` instead of `"-b 127.0.0.1:8000"`, that is a requirement for docker mapping ports

Comment: Tell me whether it works and I'll post the answer :)

Comment: And map your port: `docker run -p 8000:8000 (rest of the command)`

Comment: Sorry @Robert, still stuck and the same symptoms.

Comment: Be sure to map ports (see `docker ps`, search for the symbol `->` in PORTS column). And tell us what this outputs: `curl localhost:8000`

Comment: @Robert You da man! A combo of the things you recommended did the trick. I navigated to `localhost:8000` in my browser and the page rendered.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give some combo suggestions:

- Check that you are mapping a port to your localhost in order to access the container app:

  ```
  docker run -p 8000:8000 (rest of the command)
  ```
- Listen to `"-b 0.0.0.0:8000"` instead of `"-b 127.0.0.1:8000"`, that is a requirement for docker to map ports. So see `docker ps`, search for the symbol `->` in PORTS column (you should see `0.0.0.0:8000->8000`.

Then, navigate to `localhost:8000` in your web browser to check that your app properly renders.